# How do i add a test/resources/blah as a source path in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

So I have an eclipse project, with a src/main and src/test

I'd like to have the src/test have as sub folder src/test/resources, which is a source (ie non package) folder.

I'd still like src/test to have package folders too, eg

/src/test/com/somewhere

How do i do this? I don't really understand but when i add the src/test/resources as a source in eclipse it asks me to not have src/test as a src folder, and then everything gets confusing.

Comment: Well.. you can't have a source folder inside a source folder. The child folder will would just be interpreted as a package, it just doesn't work.

Comment: you *could* perhaps use `new Folder -> Advanced -> Link to alternate location`, but I wouldn't recommend that anyway, even if it works.